# Input fields not getting updated

Tags: reactjs

Hi I am trying to update the input fields in this way:

```
{deliverableSelection.map((deliverable, index) => (
          <>
            <Form.Group as={Row} controlId="">
              <Form.Label column sm={6}>
                {deliverable.deliverableName}
              </Form.Label>
              <Col sm={6}>
                <InputGroup>
                  {console.log(deliverable)}
                  <InputGroup.Prepend>
                    <InputGroup.Text id="btnGroupAddon2">
                      &#8377;
                    </InputGroup.Text>
                  </InputGroup.Prepend>
                  <Form.Control
                    type="number"
                    value={deliverable.deliverableValue}
                    onChange={(e) => {
                      deliverable.deliverableValue = e.target.value;
                      let demo = deliverableSelection;
                      let value = e.target.value;
                      let newVal = {
                        deliverableName: demo[index].deliverableName,
                        deliverableSlug: demo[index].deliverableSlug,
                        deliverableValue: value,
                      };
                      demo[index] = newVal;
                      setDeliverableSelection(demo);
                    }}
                  />
                </InputGroup>
              </Col>
            </Form.Group>

            <div className="separator separator-dashed my-8"></div>
          </>
        ))}
```

Now the problem coming is that the fields are not getting updated. Is it because I am updating the same data which is mapping it? could someone tell me a potential solution for it?

Comment: try `setDeliverableSelection([...demo])`

Comment: what is `deliverableSelection` in your example?

Comment: Also, you shouldn't directly mutate the state. please check @Drew answer.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are possibly mutating your state object, saving it to local variable `demo` and later doing `demo[index] = newVal;` then setting it back in state. The `deliverableSelection` never updates its reference so react doesn't rerender.

You'll want to make a copy of your state *then* update the copy and update state.

```
onChange={(e) => {
  deliverable.deliverableValue = e.target.value;

  let demo = [...deliverableSelection]; // <-- shallow copy existing state

  // Now update new object reference
  let value = e.target.value;
  let newVal = {
    deliverableName: demo[index].deliverableName,
    deliverableSlug: demo[index].deliverableSlug,
    deliverableValue: value,
  };
  demo[index] = newVal;
  setDeliverableSelection(demo);
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your component will re-render only when the state changes. Here you are updating the index of the array but the reference is still the same. for your component to re-render you have to update the array reference as well.

`setDeliverableSelection([...demo])`

Comment: While this will technically work (and likely not have any negative side-effects/results), it has the undesirable effect of mutating the current state object `demo` *before* it's spread into a new array object reference. Not mutating state is one of the React commandments.

Comment: yes, you are absolutely correct! we shouldn't mutate the states directly.